# In react native, how can I create a system where a check box is checked, then the other one one is unchecked automatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, checkbox

[image: This is the UI of the app]

Here are just two plain check boxes.
I'm using Expo Checkbox for a checkbox in react native.

I'd like to create an system where a checkbox is checked, then the other one is unchecked automatically.

Here are codes that I created so far.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import Checkbox from "expo-checkbox";

function ForChecked() {
  const [isChecked, setChecked] = useState("false");
  const [isChecked2, setChecked2] = useState("false");

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Checkbox value={isChecked} onValueChange={setChecked} />
      <Checkbox
        value={isChecked2}
        onValueChange={setChecked2}
        onPress={setChecked((pre) => !pre)}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
  },
});

export default ForChecked;
```

I thought that this would work, but somehow it didn't.
How can I accomplish this?
Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you just use radio buttons instead?

Comment: That's what a [radio group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio) is for.  There's a lot of value to not re-inventing the wheel-- better browser support, accessibility, etc, so I would start there unless there's a compelling reason not to use it.

Comment: hello, yes this behavior is like radio buttons not checkboxes. In cas if you don’t want to code your custom radio buttons you can use some packages like react-native-radio-buttons-group or react-native-simple-radio-button